# add sql data (2 tables ) from database to webpage

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I'm trying to add data from two tables to my PHP website. The data should be in a table layout. the table ' bikes' is using an ID from the manufacturers table

```
<?php
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<thead>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>Model</th>';
    echo '<th>condition</th>';
    echo '<th style="width: 10%">Price</th>';
    echo '<th style="width: 5%">&nbsp;</th>';
    echo '<th style="width: 5%">&nbsp;</th>';
    echo '</tr>';

    $products = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM bikes');

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $product['model'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $product['condition'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>£' . $product['price'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td><a style="float: right" href="editbike.php?id=' . $product['id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
        echo '<td><form method="post" action="deletebike.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="bikeId" value="' . $product['id'] . '" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" />
        </form></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</thead>';
    echo '</table>';

    }

    else {
?>
```

The other table is called manufacturers... is there a way I can add data from the manufacturers table to the website, with the data being listed next to each other as this looks like a table layout? 
(if not sure what I mean add a email and ill email screenshots of what I'm trying to do)

Comment: Have you ever heard about **Join** in SQL Server?!

Comment: and please remove extra tags, MySQL and SQL-Server are not the same,

Answer (score -1):

You will need to create a relationship between the 2 tables, e.g. add `manufacturer_id` to the `bikes` table.

You can then simply do a select across both tables:

```
$products = $pdo->query('SELECT b.*, m.* FROM bikes AS b, manufacturers AS m WHERE m.id = b.manufacturer_id');
```

Or [use a join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html):

```
$products = $pdo->query('SELECT b.*, m.* FROM bikes AS b JOIN manufacturers AS m ON m.id = b.manufacturer_id');
```

If these tables share column names, such as 'name' then you'll need to alias one of them:

```
$products = $pdo->query('SELECT b.*, m.*, m.name AS manufacturer_name FROM bikes AS b JOIN manufacturers AS m ON m.id = b.manufacturer_id');

$products['name'] = 'bike name';
$products['manufacturer_name'] = 'manufacturer name';
```

Anytime two columns have the same name the first selection will take precedence, in the above case `bikes` will take precedence, if you reverse the selections manufacturer will take precedence:

```
$products = $pdo->query('SELECT m.*, b.*, m.name AS manufacturer_name FROM bikes AS b JOIN manufacturers AS m ON m.id = b.manufacturer_id');

$products['name'] = 'manufacturer name';
$products['manufacturer_name'] = 'manufacturer name';
```

Comment: You need to make sure the tables exist and that `manufacturer_id` on the bikes table is the same as `id` on the manufacturers table.

Comment: so when i add the code above (either one), could i then add this code '  echo '<th>name</th>';  ' and ' echo '<td>' . $product['name'] . '</td>';  (added in the right place)' to display the manufacturers table as well as the bikes table... theres already a manufactures_id in the bikes table

Comment: If the tables have the same columns you'll need to add aliases, I've updated my answer to show you how to do this.

Comment: there's a foreign key in the bikes table that references from the manu' table... they don't have the same column name sorry for the confusion... im trying to get the column (name)  from the manu' table so the website displays the information from the manu' table not just the bikes table... could i email you what i mean? or should i  leave my email here and you email me?

Comment: You would do that using the examples in my answer, it'll all be part of the `$product` array. If you dump out the `$product` array (using [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) or similar) you will see it contains columns from both tables. If it doesn't it'll be because the columns have the same name and will need to be aliased as per my example.

Comment: so what part should i add to my code for this to work?

Comment: Replace `$products = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM bikes');` with `$products = $pdo->query('SELECT b.*, m.* FROM bikes AS b, manufacturers AS m WHERE m.id = b.manufacturer_id');`

Comment: once thats done could i add this code ' echo '<th>name</th>'; ' and ' echo '<td>' . $product['name'] . '</td>'; (added in the right place)' to display the thing i want?

Comment: i replaced it and it said ' Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /srv/http/public_html/admin/bikes.php on line 75'